# how do you query your existing ldap parameters?

Tags: networking, ldap, authentication

ldapsearch -A locked my computer up and upchucked about 3000 unnecessary lines (not one clearly had the information I was looking for).
Is their a quick summary search that will upchuck your ou, dn, dn etc in a format under 100 lines in response?

Comment: Do you mean you just want a list of all the supported parameters?

Comment: @Andrew Schulman I am trying to get the configured key values for ou, dn etc.. Just a summary.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "key values". Running "ldapsearch -A" will return all attributes of all objects that your query can access. Do you want returned a set of commonly useful attributes from all objects? Or all available attributes on a specific object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ldapsearch -x -ZZ -h localhost -D "cn=admin,o=tree" -b o=tree mail |grep mail:
```

will provide you with just email addresses.
You can get as detailed as you want.